# Graphics on 2nd page, as called from 1st page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics

I am using C# in Visual Studio. I want to draw a circle on second page by calling the circle method from first page. The method is called as I checked with placing different Messages but unable to see the drawing.

**Calling part on 1st page**

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Form2_point();
```

**Called part on 2nd page**

```
public void Form2_point()
{   
    r1=4;
    r2=8;
    Graphics g;
    g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    PaintEventArgs arg = new PaintEventArgs(g, rectangle);
    DrawCircle(arg, r1, r2, 10, 10);
}

private void DrawCircle(PaintEventArgs e, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Circle");
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
    //e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 30, 40, 60, 80);
}
```

How can I draw circle on 2nd page by taking input from 1st page?

Comment: Where do you ever call `f.Show()` to actually *display* the second form?

Comment: I think you need to set some valid dimensions on the clipping rectangle that you use as argument to PaintEventArgs as well as on the Form2 (f) itself. And don't forget to dispose the created Graphics object. But a better solution may be to do the drawing in the OnPaint event handler of Form2 and then call f.Invalidate() whenever you want the circle redrawn.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what the issue is. But based on the little bit you did post, it seems you have a completely wrong idea of how to use the Winforms API. First, _never_ call `CreateGraphics()`. Draw _only_ while handling a `Paint` event. Second, if you want to reuse code that draws, don't make one `Form` class depend on another; put the code to be reused in a separate class from both, and let both use that class.